# Itext XMLWorker with Websphere 8.0 not invoking my servlet.

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat7, websphere-8

I am trying to create PDF using itext and XMLWorker. I have a servlet which will interact with DB and give Image as response. The problem is if i use Tomcat 7.0 as my server image is getting printed in PDF. But if i use Websphere it's not invoking the servlet to render the image. Is there any config should i do?

Comment: is the path the same?

Comment: Ya. Now I tried in local websphere server and it's working fine . But while deploying, it's not invoking.

Comment: @SatheshS, Can you please let me know how did you resolve this issue? I'm also having the same issue...